# ValueError when using Basemap.scatter()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe with a bunch of time series geographical data that I am mapping.

```
my_map = Basemap(
projection="tmerc",
lon_0=-105,
lat_0=39,
ellps="WGS84",
llcrnrlon=coords[0] - extra + 0.01 * w,
llcrnrlat=coords[1] - extra + 0.01 * h,
urcrnrlon=coords[2] + extra + 0.03 * w,
urcrnrlat=coords[3] + extra + 0.01 * h,
lat_ts=0,
resolution="h",
suppress_ticks=True)

my_map.readshapefile("...", "colorado")

df_map = pd.DataFrame({
    "poly": [Polygon(xy) for xy in my_map.colorado],
    "business_name": [business["NAME"] for business in my_map.colorado_info]
})

map_points = pd.Series([Point(my_map(mapped_x, mapped_y)) for mapped_x, mapped_y in zip(df[1], df[0])])
business_points = MultiPoint(list(map_points.values))
county_polygons = prep(MultiPolygon(list(df_map["poly"].values)))
colorado_points = filter(county_polygons.contains, business_points)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
map_colors = [date2num(i) for i in df["datecreated"]]
dev = my_map.scatter(
    [geom.x for geom in colorado_points],
    [geom.y for geom in colorado_points],
    5, marker="o", lw=.25,
    c=map_colors, edgecolor='w', cmap=plt.cm.viridis,
    alpha=0.9, antialiased=True,
    label='Business Locations')
```

When I go to call `my_map.scatter()`, it keeps throwing this error:

> ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "689576.0" to_rgb: Invalid rgb
>   arg "689576.0" cannot convert argument to rgb sequence

My dataset has roughly 1.3M data points, with multiple, repeated dates correlating to different events. I would it wouldn't be a problem to use a colorbar for that many dates, seeing as there are 16M colors. [Looking at the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter()`, the `c` arg can be "a single color format string, or a sequence of color specifications of length N, or a sequence of N numbers to be mapped to colors".

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Full Traceback: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23813647/

[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://pastebin.com/zDpAC6Tb).

Comment: It looks like the value you're passing into `scatter` for the `c` argument is not an accepted value. Try switching it up by converting to in int, string, or list. play around with it

Comment: It works in this case: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/lloydm/kBn5n

Comment: Could you please include the complete stack trace in the question? Are you sure that it is the `c` argument that is the culprit and not something else?

Comment: @mkrieger1 added the traceback URL in the post.

Comment: Even [this example](http://pastebin.com/N7Em46G2) works for me. So I guess you should create a [MCVE] which is runnable (remove the shapefile import, define `df` or remove it, remove as much of the code as to still reproduce the error).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added the MCVE! Link is at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to install `fiona`, so I cannot run your code. If all of those 105 lines of code are absolutely necessary to reproduce the error, I fear you will not find a solution. Otherwise, reconsidering the meaning of "minimal" might help us here.

Comment: That's okay, I appreciate the trying! I'm not sure how else to reproduce it, I was able to test the issue with the same size DataFrame, so I'm wondering if there is a step I'm missing. Does the `c` arg need to have normalised data? i.e., no repeats?